# Prevent Rodent incursion along a retaining wall

Tags: foundation, gardening

I live in a first generation suburb.  The retaining wall behind me is starting to crack, but it is not mine to permanently fix. After I concrete over any cracks in the retaining wall, I would like to do whatever I can prevent rats from burrowing next to that wall. I'm not a rat fan.

I would like to lay down some material along the retention wall and make it difficult for the rats to burrow. How wide and deep should I go? Fill it with big stones that are hard to move by a rat? fill with smaller stones that won't leave enough room for a rat to wiggle through? Bury some wire mesh under the grass along the wall?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are barking up the wrong tree on your ideas.  Either buy and keep a Dash Hound; They have been used for generations to mitigate rodent infestation.  And they have a great time too.  Or consult a pro about the safe use of a rat poison regimen.

Comment: I didn't appreciate your answer at first. You recommended that I buy a dog or buy some professional services. Which is not what I was really looking for from a diy forum.  However, it did cause me to rethink about 'barking up the wrong tree.'  So I reconsidered what I was planning, and maybe I just shouldn't stay as far away from the wall as I possibly could. So now, my landscaping will be at least a lawnmower's width away from the wall. Keep the grass manageable.  I didn't have problems with rats when it was all flat, open to the weather, grass.